# Docker vs local build for baking on mainnet?

Tags: baking, docker, setup

It seems some people encounter difficulty setting up a baking operation using docker on mainnet.

My question is two-fold

1) does docker offer some advantage in principle vs an actual build on local machine ?

2) is docker build as much supported as simple straight build or cause too much additional complications that its overall value add is unclear ? (Example issues are: management of access control, connectivity with ledger etc...)

Answer (score 6):

The docker builds are generally aimed at those individuals who are not comfortable with, or have no experience in compiling software. There is no advantage over running docker builds vs compile on your own; the code is the same. The docker builds are indeed supported by the core devs. With each new release of the core code, the docker images are also updated. Utilizing the docker builds does present additional challenges in getting all the separate images working together if you intend to bake. If you just want to run a node, the docker method is quick and simple. If you want to bake, however, docker may introduce additional complexity.

Comment: just to note that as someone who has build over 20 nodes from source and someone who is proficient with unix shells, I still much prefer docker method for building out nodes, mostly for the sane maintenance aspects of it. As utdrmac pointed out, private baking node is probably the only exception to this rule for the reasons he stated.

Answer (score 4):

Of course the use of the Docker makes it easier to build a node, and it is useful for people with an initial level of knowledge of programming on Linux. The fact is that when you build a node for baking through the Docker, you may encounter errors that will not be easy enough to understand. I advise you to collect the node by the steps prescribed in [this manual](https://gist.github.com/dakk/bdf6efe42ae920acc660b20080a506dd).

Answer (score 0):

I tried docker and could not get my head/logic to follow it, yes i could launch it but then..... dono what is happening. compiling and running it from source has worked flawlessly for me also allowed me to learn how things worked from the get go.

also the amount of helping tools available to bakers who build from source is growing fast also.

Comment: could you try to be more specific in your answer please ? it's hard to actually extract information from your comments. thanks!